# Need Raster skew from one side in Paper js vector library

Tags: raster, paperjs, skew

i am new with paper js, i need skew image from one side, please view the image link. i need one side skew on image (Raster)
 [i explain in image what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yoyhc.png).

var m = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
var raster = new Raster({
    matrix: m,
    source: 'effel.jpg',
    position: view.center,
    });

raster.skew(1, 0);
raster.scale(0.25);